# Setting up local environment for Python

Tags: python, local, development-environment

I'm trying to transfer from using PHP to Python, Im looking to change to Python as it seems a much more versatile language able to work across a range of scenarios. The sort of things i plan to use it for range from web app development (using django), NLP, machine learning and automation using mechanize.

One of the things I really liked about PHP was MAMP, the way it creates an htdocs folder, a localhost:8888 url, and a MySQL server, with pretty much 0 effort.

Is there something similar with Python ? I'm not necessarily looking for a GUI like MAMP (although that would be good) - what are the other options for setting up a local environment?

Comment: It depends on what you are looking for... for example django ships with everything you may need on a development machine.

Comment: What is your operating system?  You want to stay on Mac?

Comment: @wim - yes its a mac i would be working on

Comment: @Faust - Ive updated the question re. what im looking to do using Python

Comment: You, probably, won't need anything else. Except for (in some cases) `virtualenv` and `pip` (to install python packages). And of course a nice IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Python excels in this area, but as with most tools exactly what you do depends on what you want. In particular, you certainly want [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/), Python's configuration and dependency -isolation tool.

You may also want a development-configuration management tool such as [buildout](http://buildout.org), but that is more controversial as there are many other great, language-agnostic tools that overlap. (For example, you may want to set up your environment using [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) and leave your host OS behind.)

Neither virtualenv nor buildout will set up Apache for you OotB, but you do have the option of installing django, zope, or many other Python frameworks and applications with [buildout recipes](http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/docs/recipelist.html). There are recipes for apache too, but most Python web development that I know of is agnostic of the httpd, so you might end up not wanting it.